# How to fetch the record that have the closest date?

Tags: vba, excel

Here is the excel raw data example

- StaffID   Date  Accumulative Balance
- s15    15/12/2015 31
- s15  31/12/2015 64
- s15  3/4/2016   65
- S98   13/4/2016   65
- ......

Now i want to generate a report in excel .
This report i have to show every staff starting accumulative balance from 1/1/2016-31/3/2016.

Starting accumulative balance refer to the accumulative balance before 1/1/2016 .

For example , for staff S15 ,the balance should be 64 (most closest Accumulative Balance before 1/1/2016 .

## Question

Any VBA function or method useful in this case to get the closest date record ,so that I can fetch that record field(Balance).

Btw, the starting date (1/1/2016) should be stored in a datetype variable-

```
startdate
```

## Update

i mean is there any vba function

say , abc(1/1/2016,table1(range(A:A)) 
it can help me to find the date closest to 1/1/2016 and before 1/1/2016 in that column- range(A:A)

Output: 31/12/2015

Then , i can do the next step :getting the balance in that row -31/12/2015

Comment: Your question is *too broad*, or simply unclear. Please see [ask].

Comment: Why VBa? An array version of INDEX MATCH will do this.

Comment: @Scott Craner  as i implement the code and generate the report in excel , i use VBA as coding

Comment: @Scott Craner i know what u mean . But my datatype is date ,It cant perform the function

Comment: What happens if there are two dates with the same distance to 1/1/2016 but with different values?

Comment: @Tom it group by the staffID. it only search for the records with same STAFFID .

Comment: I'm aware of that. Maybe I wasn't clear. Which value would be the "correct" one, for the same staffID, two dates with a different distance and different values.

Comment: @Tom This case should not happen .As the table is sorted by date in ascending .As i want to get 1/1/2016 Accumulative Balance ,i should get the latest accumulative Balance (<1/1/2016) .Even though on 31/12/2015 have two records , it should get the later time value on 31/12/2015 .As it has the most updated Accumulative Balance before 1/1/2016

Comment: I do not see what the fact that the value is a date or not,  I got 64 with the following formula using your data in Column A,B and C.  `=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(DATEVALUE("1/1/2016"),B:B))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will deliver this answer, but I have to emphasize, that the criticism brought forward to you in the comments is still justified.

```
Sub findClosestDate()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i, j, currDist As Long
Dim startDate As Date

Set ws = Worksheets(1)
With ws
    i = 1
    j = 1
    closestDistLine = 1
    startDate = "01.01.2016"
    currDist = .Cells(i, 2) - startDate

    Do While .Cells(i, 1) <> ""
            newDist = .Cells(i, 2) - startDate
            If newDist >= currDist Then
                closestDistLine = i
                currDist = newDist
            End If
            If .Cells(i, 1) <> .Cells(i + 1, 1) Then
                .Cells(j, 5) = .Cells(i, 1)
                .Cells(j, 6) = .Cells(closestDistLine, 3)
                currDist = .Cells(i + 1, 2) - startDate
                newDist = .Cells(i + 1, 2) - startDate
                j = j + 1
            End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End With

End Sub
```

For this code to work, you have to sort your table alphabetically after the staff-id.

How does it work

1. It loops through the rows, checks the distance of the current line to the startdate.
2. If the distance is closer to the startdate, the line of that row is saved in `closestDistLine`
3. If all entries of the current staff-id are found, staff-id and value in the row of closest distance will be written into columns `5` and `6`

HTH

Comment: wt if i want to add one more condition .Only for the staff doesn't have the record within the range ( 1/1/2016-31/3/2016) ,have to find for their closest Accumulative Balance . For example , for staff- S19  ,there is records within the range .No need to check the closest accumulative balance for him .

Comment: Just add another `if`-block enclosing everything currently in the `Do While`-loop. Try to come up with something for yourself first. :)